# SQL Query Help for Chart Data

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**Here is our goal:**

We want to select each month and the revenue gained for each month, for a particular user.

**Here are our tables**

product, purchase, user, months

user 1..* product, product 1..* purchase

product has a column 'user_id' and purchase has a column 'product_id'

months is just a table that contains each month as a string.  Currently, we are using this to do some left joins as you can see below.

```
SELECT months.name, IFNULL(sum(purchase.price), 0) as revenue
FROM months
    LEFT JOIN purchase
        ON DATE_FORMAT(purchase.purchase_date, '%M') = months.name
        AND DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, '%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y')
        AND purchase.status = 2
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY months.id ASC;
```

Which works great for ALL of the users and ALL of the purchases made this month (Purchase status of 2 means complete).  The next part is how do I filter this based on a user id? The table 'product' has the user_id we're looking for, and table purchase has a 'product_id'.  Everytime I try something it either does nothing or it removes all of the null values, which we don't want.

**ATTEMPT @NathanialWools**
The where clause will remove all of the rows with a revenue of zero (or null, because of the IFNULL statement).  This is what I tried:

```
SELECT name, IFNULL(sum(purchase.price), 0) as revenue
FROM months
    LEFT JOIN purchase
        ON DATE_FORMAT(purchase.purchase_date, '%M') = months.name
        AND DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, '%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y')
        AND purchase.status = 2
    LEFT JOIN product
        ON product.id = purchase.product_id
WHERE product.user_id = 1
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY months.id ASC;
```

Comment: I'm confused about why `product` has a `user_id` attribute.

Comment: a user has 1...* products, as in users can sell their products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inner-select Seems to do the trick.  The left join on the purchase alone was not enough filtering.  Here is the solution that works for me:

```
SELECT m.name, IFNULL(sum(b.price), 0) as revenue
FROM months as m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT price, purchase_date, status
           FROM purchase, product
           WHERE purchase.product_id = product.id
           AND product.user_id = 1) as b
    ON DATE_FORMAT(b.purchase_date, '%M') = m.name
    AND DATE_FORMAT(b.purchase_date, '%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%Y')
    AND status = 2
GROUP BY m.name
ORDER BY m.id ASC
```

Where you would obviously change the '1' based on which user you wanted to look at.

Thanks everyone for pitching in, made debugging faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of users you could start with that, join to months, then join to product.  (if you don't just start with product).

```
SELECT u.user_id, m.name, IFNULL(sum(p.price), 0) as revenue 
FROM user u
CROSS JOIN months m
LEFT JOIN product d
    ON u.user_id = d.user_id
LEFT JOIN purchase p
    ON DATE_FORMAT(p.purchase_date, '%M') = m.name
    AND DATE_FORMAT(p.purchase_date, '%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y')
    AND p.product_id = d.product_id
    AND p.status = 2
WHERE u.user_id = <user you care about>
GROUP BY u.user_id, m.name
ORDER BY m.id ASC;
```

Comment: your first solution doesn't seem to actually do anything.  2 Left joins will just include all of the data instead of filtering, correct?

Comment: Ah good point, if you want 0's then the second is the way to go.  I will edit the sollution.

Comment: Thanks, I look forward to it.

Comment: Ahh! The solution produces the same result as the where-clause.  Meaning it removes the nulls before we set them to zero.

Comment: I am a bit confused--It should produce a row for every user since we are left joining to users.

Comment: Ahhh.  What I was looking for was a month row for 1 user.  Meaning revenue for each month of this year for the logged-in user.  Make sense?  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN on product, and add a WHERE clause where user_id is null or user_id is equal to your value.

Comment: Tried and Edited the Main.  The where clause seems to remove all of the null rows before we set them to 0.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try?

```
SELECT months.name, u.user_id, sum(IFNULL(purchase.price, 0)) as revenue
FROM months
    LEFT JOIN purchase pu
        ON DATE_FORMAT(purchase.purchase_date, '%M') = months.name
        AND DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date, '%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y')
        AND purchase.status = 2
    LEFT JOIN product pr
        ON pr.product_id = pr.product_id
    LEFT JOIN user u
        ON u.user_id = pr.user_id
GROUP BY pu.name, u.user_id
ORDER BY months.id ASC;
```

Comment: Did try this, and utilizing multiple left joins only adds data to our collection rather than filtering it by a userid.